# Phrase for habitual scoffing at someone & then asking for his help

Tags: phrase-requests

In our cultural language we say that `he always spit & then lick the same spot`... at least something like this. However, can I get some convenient phrase for such a person habit.

Comment: What is the phrase in you language, not translated?

Comment: sir it's in Urdu not English

Comment: Still might be helpful...

Comment: In Urdu `Thook Kar Chatna` meaning `licking after spitting` but well its very strongly negative phrase

Comment: In BeE, 'scoffing someone' sounds rather odd, as the verb isn't normally used transitively except as slang for 'eating'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's odd, _scoffing someone_ sounds fine to me. The title might be better as _habitually scoffing someone_ or _habitual scoffing of someone_.

Comment: Aren't you asking about admitting that you are wrong and displaying humility? Can you please include an example?

Comment: [These Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scoffed+the+man%2Cscoffed+the+lot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscoffed%20the%20lot%3B%2Cc0) seem to support my view; in fact, there are 745 000 Google hits for "scoffed at him" and only 8000 for "scoffed him" in a general search. Though I wouldn't have edited OP's title, as KF has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner version of Frank's phrases is **"Don't foul your own nest"**.  It is less clear that either of these match the intent as expressed in the title of this post about mocking someone then asking for help later.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the _spit & lick_ at all - _burning your bridges_ might be a fit for the title; after enduring habitual scoffery it's quite possible that the scoff would not want to provide help to the scoffer.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't bite the hand that feeds you**

is a proverb applying to this situation.

It can be re-ordered – 'He's biting the hand that feeds him' – but the proverb is far more commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

These phrases convey a similar meaning but they don't appear to be used in their literal meaning very often.

*Don't shit on your own doorstep* and *Don't shit where you eat* are warnings against doing the *spit and lick* that you describe.

I can't think of any that you could use to describe someone. By that I mean I don't think I've heard *He shits on own doorstep* or *He shits where he eats* or similar.

**As it turns out, neither of these are suitable, unless you use them in the literal sense**.

In the metaphorical [?] sense they mean something else, something that I was unaware of until I checked.

It would seem that, in the US, *Don't shit where you eat* means *Don't have sex with people at your place of employment* which would be nothing like the authors *spit and then lick the same spot*.

I've also checked what I consider to be the UK version *Don't shit on your own doorstep* and it also appears to mean the same as the *...where you eat* version.

Answer (score 1):

**Come Crawling Back**

> **crawl back** to somebody:​ to admit that you were wrong and ask someone to forgive you or ask them for something that you were offered and refused in the past: *Don't come crawling back to me when she throws you out!* - [Cambridge dictionary online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crawl-back-to-sb)

Comment: I think this is close enough to deserve an upvote. It's not quite the same as the Urdu phrase as that implies a tendency to act in this way habitually, however I believe that it's as close as we can get in English.